# Javascript setTimeOut function within a jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I am trying to use the timeout function within a jsp. But it doesn't work.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function hol_logs() {
          var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
            "getlogs.jsp",
            { method: 'get',parameters: 'jobId=<%=job%>', onComplete: zeige_logs }
          );

          setTimeOut("hol_logs()", 10000);
    }
        
    function zeige_logs( originalRequest ) {
           $('output').innerHTML = originalRequest.responseText;
    }

    hol_logs();
</script>
```

As you can see, the function `hol_logs` is supposed to be called every 10sec (I also tried it without the `()`, with no effect). It definitely gets executed once (at the end of the script), but the `setTimeOut` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive-  it should be `setTimeout`.
You also shouldn't use a string for the code part:

```
setTimeout(hol_logs, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `setTimeout`.
Also, wrap your call into function, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  hol_logs(); 
}, 10000);
```